# Email contents of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Is there any way to copy the contents of UITableView? 
This is keeping in mind the fact that it IS in the same view as the table, however, the cells are custom (however only with 4 rows of text, each containing 4 labels).
Ideally I would like an excel like table to be sent via email, but I would like to find a way to copy each cell (and keep the formatting between them) and send it in a useful manner. (The information is feedback, with several categories rated out of 5!)

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for doing that, you'll have to generate yourself the file with the content of the table. Just go one by one on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a CSV using this code (am looking now)

```
 + (NSString *)returnCreatedCSVFileNameFromColumns:(NSArray *)columns andDetails:(NSArray *)details {
//Create CSV string:
__block NSString *csvString = [[NSString alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *detailsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *columnsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Current Column:

for (TableColumn *column in columns) {
    //Add the title for the column we are looping through:
        csvString = [csvString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", column.displayName]];
}

[columnsArray addObject:csvString];

csvString = @"";

for(Individual *individual in details)
{
    for (TableColumn *tableColumn in columns)
    {
            csvString = [csvString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[tableColumn columnValueForIndividual:individual] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"/"] ? : @""]];
    }

        csvString = [csvString stringByAppendingString:@","];
    }

    csvString = [csvString stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
}

[detailsArray addObject:csvString];

csvString = @"";

csvString = [csvString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", [columnsArray objectAtIndex:0], [detailsArray objectAtIndex:0]]];

//Save csv to docs folder:
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"current_share.csv"];

NSData *csvFileData = [csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([csvFileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
    DLog(@"File written to: %@", filePath);
}
else
    DLog(@"Saving file error");

return filePath;
}
```

I've used this to create a CSV file and return the local file path which can then be emailed somewhere. Obviously your data structure may be different but you should be able to get the general idea ... ? If not please let me know (I have omitted some code).

Comment: Right, but if I have many different labels (since it's custom string) is there any to keep the distance between them (formatting) without pressing space a couple dozen times? :-)

Comment: Well it's a CSV so you can separate them with a ',' ?